# Use recaptcha-enterprise in android

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9zqA.png)

In gradle file, i import com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha, but in my class file, i can't use it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02YJa.png)

I tried download aar file from maven repository, and import it in my module, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please do not post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0):

I check file in recaptcha package, i find tips as follow
[image]
And then, i check my kotlin compiler abi version, it is lower than needed.
[image]
So, i should change kotlin compiler abi version, and then i find my android studio version is 3.5.3 and it is just support api version 1.3.
If you want to support api version 1.8, you should download new android studio.
You can find the correct android version from this [website](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details).